# C# using statement at the top of the code page

Tags: c#, .net

Almost all C# files have `using` statements at the top of the page

i.e.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

//code....
```

What do the `using` statements mean that are at the top of the page? Why is the syntax different from other `using` statement declarations.

i.e.

```
using (ResourceType resource = expression) statement
```

Comment: `using` at the top of the code page means something more like `#import` or `imports`. I agree with you - it would have been better to use some other keyword in this spot.

Comment: @MusiGenesis It's only somewhat related to "import" the using directive does no "import"ing. The using directive is entirely syntactic sugar. It signifies that you are using the specified namespace implicitly in your code (When there aren't collisions)

Comment: @mckay: C#/using is _exactly_ the same as VB/Imports

Comment: @Henk Holterman Ah, yes, it is just like the VB imports, but it is quite different from the Java import as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189154/c-using-statement-at-the-top-of-the-code-page/4189181#4189181

Comment: Wow, and I thought putting my answer as a comment would spare me from this. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are [using directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx). They tell the compiler which namespaces to look in to find the classes you use in your code.

They look different (and are completely different) from the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) which defines a scope for disposable objects.

Answer (score 1):

The [using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) (as opposed to the using statement you mention that handles disposable objects) allow you to not specify the whole namespace of a class

i.e. if there is a class called

```
System.IO.FileStream
```

Then you could put

```
using System.IO;
```

And refer to it as

```
FileStream
```

(as long as the compiler can only determine a single thing that might mean)

Answer (score 1):

These statements tellt he compiler which namespaces to look in to find the classes you are using in the code.

For example if you have

```
using System.IO;
```

Then your code to read all text of a file can be

```
File.ReadAllText("MyFile.txt");
```

rather than

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllText("MyFile.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

`using` is a contextual keyword; it has more than one meaning, depending on how it's used.

At the head of a .cs file, it works like the java `import` instruction, specifying namespaces to search when looking for a type. If it's not listed, you must fully qualify types you use, which gets cumbersome. However, importing namespaes you don't need is wasteful and can introduce ambiguities.

Comment: -1 for comparing it to java import in this manner. Java Import works like adding a reference and adding a using. C#'s using does not do all of what Java's import does. Also, it isn't "wasteful" in performance at runtime, though it will affect compile time trivially. It can introduce ambiguities though.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/zhdeatwt(v=VS.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/zhdeatwt%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

> The using keyword has two major uses:
>
> As a directive, when it is used to
>   create an alias for a namespace or to
>   import types defined in other
>   namespaces. See [using Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/sf0df423%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).
>
> As a statement, when it defines a
>   scope at the end of which an object
>   will be disposed. See [using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

1) The `using` keyword followed by a resource path provides a reference to a library in order to use additional/special classes and methods. This is similar to `import`-like keywords in other languages.

2) The `using` statement obtains the resource specified, executes the statements and disposes the object (releases from memory).

Comment: Disposing an object does not release it from memory. It is just an ordinary method intended to clean up unmanaged resources like close a database connection, release system resources, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The kind of usings that exists are the

[`using` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx), the one on top of files. It has two versions

1. `using System.Text;` - search this namespace for types that are not given by a fully qualified name. Similar to the %PATH% system variable.
2. `using Project = PC.MyCompany.Project;` - an "alias" for a type or namespace

The other kind of using is the [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx), the one with `using (var foo = IDisposable){...}`
This is a shortcut for a try-catch-block that calls Dispose on the foo-variable at the end.